# How to generate squircle curve with two points and two tangent angle

Tags: geometry, algebraic-curves

The standard squircle curve equation is: $(x-a)^4 + (y-b)^4 = r^4$

What I do is not generating the whole curve, but just like AutoCAD, I give two points with two tangent angles respectively by clicking mouse on the screen. There is no problem if the two tangent angles are vertical, that is 0, 90, 180, 270, 360.see Pic.1

[image: Pic.1 squircle curve with the vertical angle]

But if the two tangent angles are not vertical, let's say the first one is 290 degree and the second one 65 is degree, I have no idea how to generate the curve with these information. The Pic.2 is a curve generated by one software use the unvertical tangent angle, as seen from the curve shape, I don't think that is a standard squircle curve, but I still wonder how can I generate a squircle curve with two points and two unvertical tangent angle. If there is anyone who is familiar with this, I hope you can give me some clue about this. and if my description is not clear, please let me know, I will try my best to let you understand.Thank you.

[image: Pic.2 the squircle curve generated by unvertical tangent angle.]

Comment: @flawr Thanks for your editing. It looks more intuitive now.

Comment: With two points and two tangents you have 4 equations for 3 parameters ($a$, $b$ and $r$). It cannot be done, in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arentio already mentioned it is not possible to produce the second image with the given formula and axes that are rectangular to each other. But what You *could* do to produce that image is just applying an linear transform (or an *affine* transform, but you can absorb the "affine part" into $a$ and $b$).

Basically you know the tangents through $A$ and $B$ and you can easily determine their intersection $P$. Without loss of generality we can assume that $P=\vec{0}$. Then we just need to apply the a linear transformation $T$ that maps $\vec{PA}$ to $\vec{PA'}$ and $\vec{PB}$ to $\vec{PB'} $respectively. Then we are back in the "rectangular" case where we already have the means to draw the "squircle".

[image]

To map the basis $(\vec{PA},\vec{PB})$ to the cannonical basis we use the transformation matrix $U = (\vec{PA} \mid \vec{PB})$ and similarly to map the basis $(\vec{PA} \mid \vec{PB})$ to the cannonical basis we use the transformation matrix $V= (\vec{PA'} \mid \vec{PB'})$. So we could describe $T$ for the case $P=0$ as $T = UV^{-1}$ or for $P \neq 0 $ as $v \mapsto UV^{-1} (v-P) + P$.

---

EDIT: I'm gonna make some example calculations based on estimated values for the example above. In the following I omit the vector arrows and omit the transposed sign `()^t` too for the sake of simplicity.

$P = 0$, $A = (1,1.5), PB = (-1,2)$. I assume that $A' = \Vert PA \Vert e_1  ,B' = \Vert PB \Vert e_2  $ i.e. $PA' = (1.80,0)$ and $PB' = (0,2.23)$, and so

$U = (PA \mid PB) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1.5 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, V = (PA' \mid PB') = \begin{pmatrix} 1.80 & 0 \\ 0 & 2.23 \end{pmatrix}$

Then $T = UV^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0.55 & -0.44 \\ 0.83 & 0.98\end{pmatrix}$

So in this case we transform the coordinate system with $T$

$$ \begin{pmatrix} r \\ s \end{pmatrix} = T^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}  = \begin{pmatrix} 1.2019x + 0.4006y \\ -1.0541x+0.7027y \end{pmatrix} $$

Then the *squircle* in the image above is given by the equation $(r-a)^4+(s-b)^4 = r^4$ for some $a,b$ and $r$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I think it should work with your solution. but sorry I don't have much knowledge about the affine transformation, could you give me some reference materials? and how does the transformation matrix U and V exactly look like? after we use the linear transformation T to transfer the original case to rectangular case and draw the "squircle", should we transfer it back to the original case, so the result is the curve shown in Pic.2?

Comment: I added an example calculation, I hope this clarifies what we do.

Comment: Thanks for your example, it is more clear for me now. but I still have a little confusion about the tangent angle, because in your solution, you said nothing about the tangent angle after transformation. for example, what's the tangent angle of the point A' and B', is it 0 degree for A' and 270 degree for B'? Is there a transformation equation for tangent angles just like the transformation matrix for the x and y coordinate?Thanks again!

Comment: Well you just have to have a vector pointing in that angle. In the example we could say that $PB$ is pointing in the direction of $110°$ from the *x-axis* (pointing to the right). So such a vector would have the direction $\dfrac{PB}{\Vert PB \Vert} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(110°) \\ \sin(110°) \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: OK, Thank you for your detail explanation, I will try this and come back if I encounter extra problems.